# calling a Flash ExternalInterface with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm trying to call a function declared with ExternalInterface in a Flash swf, using JavaScript. It worked once, but all of a sudden, it stopped working.

I have a debug version of the Flash Player, but no errors occur in Flash. Not even a "Security Sandbox Error" or something. The only error I get is the following error in JavaScript `Error: Error in Actionscript. Use a try/catch block to find error.`

I'm using AS3, exporting for Flash Player 10 and testing on Firefox 3/Safari 4, on a Mac.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [ExternalInterface.marshallExceptions](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#marshallExceptions). It should allow you to see more details about the error.

Comment: Didn't catch my fish, but taught me how to fish. Good answer.

Comment: Hi @joshtynjala - the link provided in your answer is dead.(http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#marshallExceptions)

Comment: @techytimB Fixed!

Answer (score 4):

Kinda tricky to help you solve something that 'worked once'.  But using ExternalInterface is pretty straightforward -- here's what I do:

in AS3: something like

```
...
if (ExternalInterface.available) ExternalInterface.addCallback("search", jsSearch);
...
private function jsSearch(term:String):void 
{
    new Search(data);
}
```

in JS: something like

```
...
var term = $('input#search').val();
$("#swfobject").get(0).search(term);
....
```

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure the javascript and the SWF are on the same domains otherwise use a **crossdomain.xml**
- Make sure you have added the **allowScriptAccess** parameter to the flash embed
- If you run it locally you may (but don't think it will change anything) add the location to flash players trusted ones (in the security panel).

Answer (score 0):

in your as

```
import flash.external.*;
ExternalInterface.call("return_me_some_value()");
```

and in your html

```
<script>
var super_var = 'something';

function return_me_some_value() {
  return super_var;
}
</script>
```